# Why am I getting this Key error? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to run my Dijkstra function twice so that I can figure out the shortest distance between 3 points. It works fine when I run it once, but two times returns a key error on line 38 and 44.

Code:

```py
graph = {'c1': {'c2':4, 'L1':3}, 'c2':{'c1':4, 'c3':3, 'L1':2.5}, 'c3':{'c2':3, 'L1':2}, 'L1':{'c1':3, 'c2':2.5, 'c3':2}}

def dijkstra(graph, start, goal):
    shortest_distance = {}
    predecessor = {}
    unseenNodes = graph
    infinity = float('inf')
    path = []

    for node in unseenNodes:
        shortest_distance[node] = infinity
    shortest_distance[start] = 0
    #print(shortest_distance)

    while unseenNodes:
        minNode = None
        for node in unseenNodes:
            if minNode is None:
                minNode = node
            elif shortest_distance[node] < shortest_distance[minNode]:
                minNode = node
        for childNode, weight in graph[minNode].items():
            if weight + shortest_distance[minNode] < shortest_distance[childNode]:
                shortest_distance[childNode] = weight + shortest_distance[minNode]
                predecessor[childNode] = minNode
        unseenNodes.pop(minNode)

    currentNode = goal
    while currentNode != start:
        try:
            path.insert(0, currentNode)
            currentNode = predecessor[currentNode]
        except KeyError:
            print('Path not reachable')
            break
    path.insert(0, start)

    if shortest_distance[goal] != infinity:
        print('Shortest distance: ' + str(shortest_distance[goal]))
        print('Path:' + str(path))

dijkstra(graph, 'L1', 'c2')
dijkstra(graph, 'c2', 'c3')
```

Here is the error I get:

```
Path not reachable
    dijkstra(graph, 'c2', 'c3')
  File "E:\Work\Delivery_API\Delivery.py", line 38, in dijkstra
    if shortest_distance[goal] != infinity:
KeyError: 'c3'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `unseenNodes = graph` you bind the variable `unseenNodes` to **the same** dict referenced by `graph`.

That means that any changes done on `unseenNodes` will reflect **also on `graph`**.

So, in the first `dijkstra(graph, 'L1', 'c2')` all goes good and well.

**BUT**, during that run you executed some `unseenNodes.pop(minNode)` which again, are equivalent to doing `graph.pop(minNode)`. So by the time you do `dijkstra(graph, 'c2', 'c3')` your graph has changed and doesn't look like you think it does. This is why it works when running only once.

The easy remedy is to work on a copy of `graph` to make sure it stays intact. All you need to do is change the assignment to: `unseenNodes = dict(graph)`. This creates a **copy** of `graph` (`unseenNodes` now references another separate dict, and not the one referenced by `graph`).

Comment: Very grateful. I just copy-pasted the data structure from graph to unseen nodes. Is there a more elegant way I should do it or is this fine? Thanks again!

Comment: This (my solution) is perfectly fine in my opinion. You can't go around it, in the end you need the `graph` to work on. You just don't want to change the original one. So you create a copy from which you can remove nodes un-worryingly